How do cables and cooling lines transverse the pressure hull of the International Space Station?
The International Space Station (ISS) is notable for having large amount of unpressurized equipments on its Integrated Truss Structure (ITS), including the solar panels and the radiators. The electric cable, data cable, and liquid ammonia lines clearly need to transverse the pressure hull at some point. Given the structure of the ITS, my hunch is that the cables somewhere from the S0 truss to the Destiny module. What allows these cables and lines to pass through?

Not an answer to the question (as it's not from a space industry source) but flexible hoses made of corrugated stainless steel are off the shelf items if a lot of movement is needed https://www.artifex.org.uk/ I have one on my domestic gas meter, and use 10 bar steam hoses professionally. External braiding prevents the hose from overexpanding when used in a pressure application (it may still be required in space since the hose is subject to higher pressure internally than externally) but is not used where pressure differential is small. Where movement is small a 180deg loop of pipe may suffice

The module penetrations that allow power, data, and fluids to pass through the hull are called "feedthroughs".

Feedthroughs are installed in the module structure to
route power, data, and fluids to the ISS modules. The
Node 1 module contains 160 feedthroughs, the
Laboratory module contains 100 feedthroughs, and
the Airlock module contains 40 feedthroughs. The
feedthroughs were leak tested following installation
to verify a proper installation.

The external cable or fluid connector will attach to the outside fitting on the feedthrough, and the internal one will attach to the inner fitting.
The feedthroughs are typically located in the module end cones surrounding the hatches.  Here is a typical schematic. The square with rounded corners in the center is the opening for the hatch and the outer circle is the inner rim of the module attachment mechanism.

Here is a crop from a photograph of some feedthroughs around one of the Node 2 hatches. (Taken while the module was being processed for launch).

The ICD referenced below contains a great deal of information about the individual feedthroughs.

References:
Node Element 3 to Habitation Module
Element Interface Control Document,
Part 2
IMPLEMENTATION OF LEAK TEST METHODS FOR THE INTERNATIONAL SPACE
STATION (ISS) ELEMENTS, SYSTEMS AND COMPONENTS
https://images.nasa.gov/details/KSC-03pd1887

And likely most were off-the-shelf from various vacuum equipment vendors. Modern technology relies on processing in vacuum (semiconductors in particular) so finding feedthroughs of all types is a quick look through the (right) catalog.

I'd not bet too much that this feed-through are COTS items. Sure, as long as one can make use of that, it is what will be used. The linked documentation seems to hint that partially COTS items from Parker (a renown vacuum manufacturer, proxy via Boing) are being used - but they seem to be not the whole story for the connector. From my experience "finding the right feedthrough" for this kind is not a "quick look through the right catalogue". That is only the start

In the case of Node modules, the passthroughs are within the CBM ring. Does the crew have access to them inside of the pressurized volume?

@Mys_721tx They are usually behind the interior walls. https://images.nasa.gov/details/iss034e010329 This is in Node 1 looking through the hatch into a PMA

The electrical pass throughs would typically be done with widely available hermetic versions of military type connectors such as M38999 Series 3. These are indeed 'catalog items' from many vendors.  Organic Marble posted link to SSP 50309.  On page 3-17 Figure 3.4-1 shows bulkhead connectors with cables mated from both sides.
Hermetic connectors use fused glass to seal between connector shell and contacts. Careful attention must be made when matching coefficients of thermal expansion as well as selecting surface finishes.

